# Docker container cannot connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker

Hello i have a docker container running which has my laravel app, i'm using my database from my local machine. I dont have extra container for my DB. But unfortunately i cannot connect my docker container with my mysql DB.

Here is the docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y software-properties-common tzdata
RUN echo "Asia/Dhaka" > /etc/timezone && rm -f /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y wget php8.0 php8.0-fpm php8.0-common php8.0-mysql php8.0-xml php8.0-dev php8.0-xmlrpc php8.0-curl php8.0-mbstring php8.0-zip
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN apt-get install -y php8.0-mongodb unzip
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3306
```

and here is my **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: "3"

services:
  client:
    build: ./
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    ports:
      - 5500:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    entrypoint: ./init.sh
```

when i try to access my **DB** inside from my **Container** it says

```sh
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

when i try to run my **api through postman** it gives me this

```json
{
    "status": "failure",
    "data": [],
    "error_code": 400,
    "error_message": "Something went Wrong",
    "errors": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = example@gmail.com limit 1)"
}
```

What might be the issue? my laravel app should get access from the container because i have exposed the port 3306 on my container. I have configured .env file but still i can not access the database from my application. I enter the container by docker exec and try to connect the DB but it cannot connect. So can anyone tell me that what i'm missing? 

 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you must try it with -h client  like this 

mysql -h client -u {your user name} -p

Comment: did you try to install mysql-server as well?

Comment: no i didnt install mysql-server

Comment: why should i install mysql-server when i will be using mysql-server from somewhere else? i just need the mysql-client to get access to the server. I though i was missing some ports or something @devnullΨ

Comment: @ha3an tried that to but can't connect

Comment: you need to install mysql server as well, as client can only connect to server https://superuser.com/questions/403216/difference-between-mysql-mysql-server-mysql-client-in-linux

Comment: does this file exist /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ? if so, check the permissions/owner

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam did you run database with docker ?

Comment: @ha3an sorry to say but unfortunately the mysqld.sock is not present on the directory. and i didn't run database with docker i just run the application with docker.

Comment: in first step you must run mysql server - and than use the host name for connect to it
on docker best practice you must run the database on other container and run it together

or you can use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 for the host ?

Comment: @devnullΨ no i have looked up the file but it's not there.

Comment: @NigelRen yap tried 127 as the host but nothing

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help 
but i moved my db to another place like used a hosted mysql that fixed the problem. THanks fo rall the help.